# How to add layer, created by another thread, to Axmapcontrol

Tags: multithreading, arcgis, layer

I have a geodatabase that contains raster datasets. I can read these datasets and convert them to layer. I want to add these layers, created another thread, to axmapcontrol but i got the error "vshost32 has stopped working".

I tried Invoke method, Action method and Backgroundworker but none of them worked. Actually I've found a way to do this but it is not useful. I can store layers as file and then read again with AddLayersFromFile method. It is slower than single threaded architecture but still multithreaded. However, if i am going to use layer files, why i am using geodatabase.

Finally, how can I add layers to axmapcontrol in multithreaded structure. Hope you will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, arc objects must be used in same thread as created. This thread is generally main thread because of containing axmapcontrol.

To fix "vshost32 has stopped working" error, just create layers in ui(main) thread. This operation doesnt take so much time. But creating datasets take long time. So create datasets in any thread, create layers in ui thread.

Hope it will help you.